# Creating Cumulative sum plots

Tags: r, plot, cumulative-sum

I am trying to calculate a plot as shown in the left hand side of the picture below which is a time series plot. I managed to create the plot using the timePlot command using "openair" package. I am now trying to add a Cumulative sum line on the same plot same plot which is the red line on the right hand side plot. I am not sure how to do that and I am just wondering If anyone could kindly advise me any steps that I could take to plot a line with Cumulative sum in the same left hand side plot?

(Please ignore any other feature on the right had side plot, all I am interested is to plot the red cumulative sum line in the same left hand side plot)

I would really appreciate any of your kind advise.
Many thanks,
Ayan

These are my sample codes to read data and create the plots at the left hand side:

```
 library("openair")
data = importAURN(site= "MY1", year = 2001:2005, pollutant= "nox") ## import data

## timeplot with monthly mean
timePlot(data, pollutant = "nox",avg.time = "month",smooth = T,ci=F, date.breaks = 5)
```

This is the example I am trying to achieve, I am trying to add the red cumulative sum line from the right hand side graph to the same time series graph on the left had side:

[image]

Comment: I don't get why if the right hand plots are cumulative sum plot they are decreasing sometimes and increasing someother time. Could you please explain this?

Comment: I'd bet the lines in the right hand side plots show sums or means of sliding windows. You could plot the bars first then manually calculate the window means, scale down to fit the plot window and add the right y-axis. A bit tedious but will get you what you want.

Comment: Hi Iselzer and Backlin, Sorry for the late reply, I realised that I have asked the wrong question. I can create the left hand side graph using "timePlot" command, no all I am trying to do is add a cumulative sum line (which is the red line in the second plot) on the same time plot command, but not sure how can I add that

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you provide some data in dput format for us to play with?

Comment: I'm missing something here: why use "timePlot" instead of just plotting your two vectors' worth of data using `plot` and `lines` or `ggplot` ?

Comment: For a concentration value (logically bounded below at zero) the cumulative sum must be monotonic upward. Ergo: Neither of those red lines can be a cumulative sum.

Comment: Hi Dwin, yes you are right, when I did that by hand in excel it seems the red line is something else, sorry everyone I need to go through the reference paper of this calculation to find out how the calculated the red line, I will update you when I find an answer, thanks for all your comments :)